# How to store a list of uneven numpy arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Let's say I have following numpy arrays:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1, 2])
b = np.array([1])
c = np.array([1, 4, 8, 10])
```

How can I do something like `np.vstack((a, b, c))` without any error? I know there is a pure python way `l = [a, b, c]` but that's not efficient enough. I'd  like to implement it in a numpy method. Do you have any idea? Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you know the list method is not efficient enough?

Comment: How about a Pandas dataframe?

Comment: In what sense would a list not be efficient. Memory?  Some calculation across arrays?  An object dtype array can save them, but it has basically the same limitations as the list. Look at `np.array([a,b,c])`

Comment: More on object dtype arrays here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37840862/901925

Comment: I guess it would depend on how would you like to use such a list of uneven numpy arrays. Because if you store it with object datatype, you can't use NumPy funcs that operate along `axes`. So, can you elaborate on how do you want to use such a list of arrays?

Comment: @user5779223 Did you end up solving this problem?

Comment: @WillMartin I store them in a pure python list finally...

Comment: @WillMartin And I think the pandas data frame is also a good alternative

Comment: @ user5779223 simple is better than complex =).

Answer (score 1):

```
In [863]: a = np.array([1, 2])
In [864]: b = np.array([1])
In [865]: c = np.array([1, 4, 8, 10])
```

A list of these 3 arrays:

```
In [866]: ll=[a,b,c]
```

An object dtype array made from this list:

```
In [867]: A=np.array(ll)

In [868]: A
Out[868]: array([array([1, 2]), array([1]), array([ 1,  4,  8, 10])], dtype=object)
```

`A`, like `ll` contains pointers to data objects elsewhere in memory.  In terms of memory use they are equally efficient.

```
In [870]: id(A[1]),id(b)
Out[870]: (3032501768, 3032501768)
```

You can perform a limited number of math operations on the elements of `A`, for example addition works as one might expect

```
In [871]: A+3
Out[871]: array([array([4, 5]), array([4]), array([ 4,  7, 11, 13])], dtype=object)
```

But there's little to no speed advantage, e.g.

```
In [876]: timeit [x+3 for x in ll]
100000 loops, best of 3: 9.52 µs per loop

In [877]: timeit  A+3
100000 loops, best of 3: 14.6 µs per loop
```

and other things like `np.max` don't work.  You have to test this case by case.

More details here: [Maintaining numpy subclass inside a container after applying ufunc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37840097/maintaining-numpy-subclass-inside-a-container-after-applying-ufunc) and other object array questions.

Answer (score 1):

To get numpy speed, you need to imbed the vectors into an array.  Either a 2D array or 1D array could work.  You could make an array of zeros that is large enough to hold all the values.  Then put the vectors in that array. Or, you could make a large 1D array and concatenate the vectors end to end.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1, 2])
b = np.array([1])
c = np.array([1, 4, 8, 10])

# Imbed the vectors in a 2D array 
A = np.zeros((3, max(a.size, b.size, c.size)))
A[0, :a.size] = a
A[1, :b.size] = b
A[2, :c.size] = c

# 1D array imbedding
B = np.zeros(a.size + b.size + c.size)
B[:a.size] = a
B[a.size:(a.size+b.size)] = b
B[(a.size+b.size):] = c

%timeit A+3

1000000 loops, best of 3: 780 ns per loop

%timeit B+3

1000000 loops, best of 3: 764 ns per loop
```

This has the advantage of numpy speed.  But it involves more coding work, and it is less easy to interpret the values of your arrays.

Also, to decide whether the 1D or 2D solution is better, it makes sense to think about how your using the arrays.  For example, if the values are Fourier series coefficients, then the 2D array would probably be better. With a 2D array you can keep specific elements of your vectors aligned.

However, I could also imagine applications where concatenating vectors into a single 1D array would make more sense. I hope this was helpful.